# Changing Data Types in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Im brand new to javascript, and relatively new to programming as a whole. I've been understanding the mechanics of javascript, but im stumped however in a situation like the following:

```
var dataTypes = {
  string1: "Test",
  string2: "Test",
  number1: 4,
};

console.log(typeof dataTypes.number1);
console.log(" ");

for (var x in dataTypes) {
  console.log(typeof x);
  if ((typeof x) === "string") {
    console.log(dataTypes[x]);
  } else {
    //
  }
}
```

And when I run this, my console displays the following:

```
number 

string
Test
string
Test
string
4
```

I'm so confused how `dataTypes.number1` went from being a number data type to a string. If anyone could take the time to elaborate what i have done wrong, and explain, that would be wonderful.

Answer (score 8):

Your variable `x` is the key (rather than the value) associated with each key/value pair in `dataTypes`.   Is is therefore always a string.

You need to examine `typeof dataTypes[x]` instead.

Comment: thanks! I feel silly that I overlooked that now haha.

Comment: @ColtraneNadler you can formally accept Alnitak's answer, if it's the right answer.